# How to remove Header, Footer and the first column from a flatfile in Unix?

Tags: unix

I have a bunch of incoming files that are structured with Header(H), Line identifier (L) and a Footer (F) which contains the total number of records as shown below:

```
H|STUDENT_ID|COURSE_NUMBER|CREDIT_COUNT
L|1234|E4|23
L|3487|D3|30
L|1234|Y4|19
L|1234|S2|28
F|4
```

But for my further processing, I need to have the data in the below structure:

```
STUDENT_ID|COURSE_NUMBER|CREDIT_COUNT
1234|E4|23
3487|D3|30
1234|Y4|19
1234|S2|28
```

How to do this in Unix? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `sed` in the following way

```sh
sed -i -E 's/(^)(H\||L\||F\|(0|[1-9][0-9]*))//g' <file>
```

The regex will match the pattern above and will replace it with an empty string. The `-i` option is for editing files in place and `-E` is for extended regex.

**Final edit:** I keep updating the regex, but now it should also capture more than single digit numbers!

Comment: It almost works correctly but it leaves out the footer count `4` as it is. Is there a way to remove that too using this command?

Comment: that's very thoughtful. I would actually need that because my files would surely contain record counts of more than 1 digit. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LearneR no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

One way with awk:

```
$ awk 'p!=""{print p}{sub(/^[^|]*\|/,"");p=$0}' file
```

Outpot

```
STUDENT_ID|COURSE_NUMBER|CREDIT_COUNT
1234|E4|23
3487|D3|30
1234|Y4|19
1234|S2|28
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '                        # using awk
p!="" {                        # if p has content
    print p                    # output
}
{
    sub(/^[^|]*\|/,"")         # remove the first field with sub()
    p=$0                       # copy the rest of fields to p
}' file
```